# Get all defined ClassificationTypeDefinitions?

Tags: c#, vsx

So I just tried creating a new classification type,

```
    [Export(typeof(ClassificationTypeDefinition))]
    [Name("String")]
    internal static ClassificationTypeDefinition _stringClassType;
```

But then I got a duplicate ClassificationTypeDefinition error telling me that "String" has already been defined. I didn't define it anywhere else. Soon as I renamed it to "String2" it went away. I'm *guessing* these are already defined by VS... can I get a list of the predefined ones so I know which to avoid (or which ones I can use)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops.... guess that wasn't too hard to find after all.

[MSDN: PredefinedClassificationTypeNames Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.language.standardclassification.predefinedclassificationtypenames.aspx)